# Input boxes in Forms and evaluation in gateways

Tags: forms, jbpm

Good afternoon,

I recently started using jBPM Business Central to create small process diagrams.

I want to explore the capabilities of this system in the creation of small forms that are executed in each BPMN Task. In this sense, I am trying to understand if there is a mechanism that allows the user to insert a value into an input box on a form and that the value that is inserted can be evaluated in a gateway.

Let's say I have the following BPMN diagram:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJmvh.png)

Meanwhile, in the task called "InserValue", I have created the following form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaXB5.png)

Essentially my problem is that I can't find in the options available in Business Central a way of creating a variable that is associated with the value that the user enters in that input box so that it can be used in the gateway:

For example, in the "Assignments" menu, in either Data Inputs or Data Outputs, there is no reference to the input box I created in the form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsQCp.png)

I'm sorry, but I couldn't find any reference to this in the available documentation.

Thank you for your attention

I've already checked the available documentation, namely :
https://www.jbpm.org/learn/documentation.html

I've searched on google and can't find an answer